# How to make the bootstrap 4 card component full screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is my code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            #gg{
                display:none;
            }
            video {
                transform: scale(-1, 1);
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body class="p-1">
        <div class="border-top border-primary container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary col-6 h4 p-1 mb-0">
                    Self View
                </div>
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-right border-primary col-6 h4 p-1 mb-0">
                    Remote View
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary col-6 p-1">
                    <div class="card text-white">
                        <video id="selfView" autoplay muted class="card-img" style="max-height:25vh;height:auto">
                            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div class="align-items-center bg-secondary card-footer d-flex flex-row 
                                    h4 justify-content-between mb-0 p-1">
                            <div class="muteBtn">&#x1f507;<span class="elapseTime"></span></div>
                            <div class="minMaxBtn">&#x26f6;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>              
                </div>
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary border-right col-6 p-1">
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to implement the maximize function of the media player.
So, I want to know how to make the card component to be full screen.

I have tried to do the following, but does not work:

1. add h-100,w-100 class to the card component
2. add card-fullscreen class to the card component

Besides that, the panel component is removed from Bootstrap 4.
So, I cannot use the panel component.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the class full_screen below. I implement your code with a simple onclick function on the button to make it full screen and the second click it will be back to normal.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
        #gg{
            display:none;
        }
        video {
            transform: scale(-1, 1);
            object-fit: cover;
        }
        .full_screen {
            width: 100%;
            position: fixed;
            height: 100%;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 100;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        let clicked = false;
        function myFunction() {
            let media_card = document.getElementById("media_wrapper");
            if (clicked) {
                media_card.classList.add("full_screen");
            } else {
                media_card.classList.remove("full_screen");
            }
            clicked = !clicked;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body class="p-1">
<div class="border-top border-primary container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary col-6 h4 p-1 mb-0">
            Self View
        </div>
        <div class="border-left border-bottom border-right border-primary col-6 h4 p-1 mb-0">
            Remote View
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary col-6 p-1">
            <div class="card text-white" id="media_wrapper">
                <video id="selfView" autoplay muted class="card-img" style="max-height:25vh;height:auto">
                    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                </video>
                <div class="align-items-center bg-secondary card-footer d-flex flex-row
                                    h4 justify-content-between mb-0 p-1">
                    <div id="muteBtn">&#x1f507;<span class="elapseTime"></span></div>
                    <div id="minMaxBtn" onclick="myFunction()">&#x26f6;</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary border-right col-6 p-1">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank Thieu Nguyen for your inspiration.

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <style>
            #gg{
                display:none;
            }
            .full_screen {
                width: 100vw;
                position: fixed;
                height: 100vh;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 100;
            }
            video {
                transform: scale(-1, 1);
                object-fit: cover;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script>
            let clicked = true;
            function myFunction() {
                let media_card = document.getElementById("media_wrapper");
                if (clicked) {
                    media_card.classList.add("full_screen");
                } else {
                    media_card.classList.remove("full_screen");
                }
                clicked = !clicked;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body class="p-1">
        <div class="border-top border-primary container-fluid d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary col-6 h4 p-1 mb-0">
                    Self View
                </div>
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-right border-primary col-6 h4 p-1 mb-0">
                    Remote View
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="row">
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary 
                            col-6 p-1"
                    style="height:25vh">
                    <div class="card w-100 h-100 text-white" id="media_wrapper">
                        <video id="selfView" autoplay muted class="card-body p-0">
                            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div class="align-items-center bg-secondary card-footer d-flex flex-row 
                                    h4 justify-content-between mb-0 p-1">
                            <div class="muteBtn">&#x1f507;<span class="elapseTime"></span></div>
                            <div class="minMaxBtn" onclick="myFunction()">&#x26f6;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="border-left border-bottom border-primary 
                            col-6 p-1"
                    style="height:25vh">
                    <div class="card w-100 h-100 text-white" id="media_wrapper">
                        <video id="remoteView" autoplay muted class="card-body p-0">
                            <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        </video>
                        <div class="align-items-center bg-secondary card-footer d-flex flex-row 
                                    h4 justify-content-between mb-0 p-1">
                            <div class="muteBtn">&#x1f507;<span class="elapseTime"></span></div>
                            <div class="minMaxBtn" onclick="myFunction()">&#x26f6;</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
     </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Finally, I get it done.